# What does a method look like in a lua table

Tags: methods, lua

The title says most of it but in case it does not entirely make sense what i mean is that a piece of data in a table looks like this:

```
local myTable = {"banana","apple"}
-- or
local myTable = {["banana"] = 1,["apple"]=2,}
-- functions look like this:
local myTable = {
  function banana(args) print(args) end,
  -- or
  apple = function(args) print(args) end
}
```

but im not sure what a method looks like... sure i can make them outside of the table but i would prefer it to be in the table... however when i looked the normal "dictionary/library" i did not really see anything that looked like what i needed

Comment: There's no such thing as a method in Lua, there's just the `:` syntax sugar. Have you read [the docs' OOP section](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html)? There's an example that looks like what you're after.

Comment: @AKX ok so by syntax sugar you mean its the same as a normal function in a table but executed slightly different? (like the difference between function a and function b in my table)

Comment: Your banana and apple are using another form of syntax sugar, namely that `a = function() end` and `function a() end` are equivalent.

Comment: ok i read over the docs again i see how this works now... sorry to bother you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might mean by method in lua is a function in a table.

```
t={method=function(a) return a end}
```

You can call this function like this:

```
t.method(2)--returns 2
```

However if you call this function with a colon `:` it passes table `t` as first argument:

```
t:method()--returns 't'
t:method(2)--still returns 't'
```

In fact it is equivalent to call it like this:

```
t.method(t)--returns t
```

Also it is cutomary to name the first argument `self` if it is intended to use as a 'method'. So:

```
t={method=function(self, a) return a end}
t.method()--returns nil
t.method(1)--returns nil
t.method(1, 2)--returns 2
t:method()--returns nil
t:method(1)--returns 1
t:method(1, 2)--returns 1
```